# Text with no white background in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

is there a way to write something on an image without the white background of the text?

I thought about adding a clipping of this background to the label, but it covers the text

and in the rest of my ideas there is a white background for the subtitles

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

imgbg = PhotoImage(file="background.png")
bg = Label(image=imgbg)
bg.pack()

imgbgtext = PhotoImage(file="backgroundtext.png")
x = Label(text="asd",image=imgbgtext)
x.place(x=100,y=100)

text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT, "text")
text.insert(END, "text")
text.place(x=100,y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please add the picture to your code, so we have an idea what you referring about.

Comment: You can try putting the image, the text and the text box inside a canvas using `.create_image()`, `.create_text()` and `create_window()`.

Comment: it is about any background, e.g. clouds

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to write something on an image without the white
> background of the text?
>
> I thought about adding a clipping of this background to the label, but
> it covers the text

Is that what it looks like?

On line 13 or line 14, comment it out `#text.insert`. Because of duplicates.

Change this:

```
x = Label(text="asd",image=imgbgtext)
```

to:

```
x = Label(text="asd",image=imgbgtext,compound = "right")
```

Screenshot:

[image]